# Where is the call to split files in postgres when they are greater than 1gb?

Tags: postgresql

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html

"When a table or index exceeds 1 GB, it is divided into gigabyte-sized segments. The first segment's file name is the same as the filenode; subsequent segments are named filenode.1, filenode.2, etc."

I was wondering where in the source code this is dealt with.  I have been searching for the last few hours but have had no luck

edit: if someone can lead me to the code that writes pages from the buffer to disk that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: This isn't so much a programming question as something that should be directed to PostgreSQL project support - http://www.postgresql.org/support/

Comment: I'm not saying that the functionality does not exist. I'm trying to add functionality to postgres and am hoping that someone who has experience hacking postgres can help me out.

Comment: I realize that. I'm saying that this is such a product-specific question that you'd probably have better luck in a more focused setting rather than a general software Q&A site. Who better to ask where this code exists than the people who maintain the project?

Comment: This should be asked on the Postgres hackers list: http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/

Answer (score 2):

You're mainly looking for `src/backend/storage/smgr/smgr.c` and `src/backend/storage/smgr/md.c` for relfilenode management. The main file is referred to by a `RelFileNodeBackend` and the forks by `ForkNumber`. Start with `backend/storage/smgr/README`.

`git grep` will help you find things a lot faster; a quick `cd src; git grep --color relfilenode` immediately helped to find relevant areas of the codebase.

Buffer cache management and dirty write-out is quite separate. It's complicated by the use of the bgwriter (background writer), which eagerly writes dirty buffers in shared memory to disk without blocking the actively working backend(s). I'm not especially familiar with that part of the code, but a bit of time with `git grep` and the [developer documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html) should help you find your way around.